# How to use async function with key value pairs Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, debugging, web, google-chrome-extension

Inside a function I have an async function which initializes the variables(defineVariables) by calling another async function called `getLocalStorageValue` that returns a promise. When the defineVariables function is done setting all the variables, it calls another function called response which alerts `startTimeHour.value` and `endTimeHour.value`. However the values are undefined. What should I do?

The Code:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener(function() {
    let startTimeHour;
    let endTimeHour;
    let startTimeMin;
    let endTimeMin;

    defineVariables();

    async function defineVariables(){
        startTimeHour = await getLocalStorageValue("startTimeHour");
        endTimeHour = await getLocalStorageValue("endTimeHour");
        startTimeMin = await getLocalStorageValue("startTimeMin");
        endTimeMin = await getLocalStorageValue("endTimeMin");
        response();
    }
    function response(){
      if(startTimeHour != null && endTimeHour != null){
        alert(startTimeHour)
        alert(endTimeHour)
      }else{
        alert("could not get values")
      }

    chrome.tabs.query({active:true,currentWindow:true},(tabs)=>{
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id,'execoverlay',(resp)=>{
         console.log(resp.msg)
      })
    })
  }
    
}, {url: [{urlMatches : 'https://mail.google.com/'}]});

async function getLocalStorageValue(key) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
          chrome.storage.sync.get(key, function (value) {
              resolve(value);
          })
      }
      catch (ex) {
          reject(ex);
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: Sounds like `getLocalStorageValue` fulfills the returned promise with `undefined`.

Comment: Use devtools to inspect the actual contents of variables. You'll see that the result of chrome.storage.sync.get is an object that contains the requested keys as properties so the easiest fix is `resolve(value[key])` instead of `resolve(value)`

Comment: @wOxxOm you can add that as an answer. It works perfectly! Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Try using

```
return response()
```

so it runs after all the variables have been set.

Comment: Hi @tallybee the code you submitted didn't change the outcome. Is there another way I can do this?